# check for object is undefined works only on first array item

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if the object properties 'compliancestatus' and 'comments' are empty, undefined, undeclared i.e. no real value.

I am first checking that the item exists in the object array and my console.log shows that the values do exist and that both object properties are undefined.

The issue is that the second object triggers the else (obj array after2) somehow...

My object is created using:

```
// Create the object.
let contentObj = new Object();
contentObj.prefix = clausePrefix;
contentObj.no = clauseNo;

    if (clauseComplianceStatus != null) {
        contentObj.compliancestatus = clauseComplianceStatus;
    }

    if (clauseComments != null) {
        contentObj.comments = clauseComments;
    }
```

code

```
        // Check if current iteration exists in the content array.
        if (content.some(e => e.prefix === tempOBJ.content[y].prefix && e.no === tempOBJ.content[y].no)) {
            // THIS WORKS FOR ALL OBJECTS
            let currentIterationIndexOfClauseNo = content.findIndex(e => e.prefix === tempOBJ.content[y].prefix && e.no === tempOBJ.content[y].no);

            if (!content[currentIterationIndexOfClauseNo].compliancestatus && !content[currentIterationIndexOfClauseNo].comments) {
                // THIS WILL ONLY WORK FOR THE FIRST OBJECT
            } else {
                // SECOND OBJECT EXECUTES HERE FOR SOME REASONS DESPITE HAVING BOTH VALUES 'undefined' THE SAME AS THE FIRST OBJECT.
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you completely re-write the whole code example and make it much cleaner without irrelevant code and with shorter names (single-character preferred)? it's very time-consuming for us to read all this

Comment: hopefully this made it more clear, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I'll have to ask this way. Have you checked if your currentIterationIndexOfClauseNo actually changes? The code is still a little bit hard to understand, but I have one small suggestion to make (no solution but makes the code a bit simpler). Are the values of the first object also both `undefined`?

```
const obj = content.find(e => e.prefix === tempOBJ.content[y].prefix && e.no === tempOBJ.content[y].no); // will be undefined if nothing was found
if (obj !== undefined) {
        if (!obj.compliancestatus && !obj.comments) {
            // THIS WILL ONLY WORK FOR THE FIRST OBJECT
        } else {
            // SECOND OBJECT EXECUTES HERE FOR SOME REASONS DESPITE HAVING BOTH VALUES 'undefined' THE SAME AS THE FIRST OBJECT.
        }
}
```

Comment: currentIterationIndexOfClauseNo is defintley changing (it's in a loop which iterates over the array of objects. The values of the first object are also both 'undefined'

Comment: Ok...that's interesting...maybe provide a bit more context or try console.logging the results of !obj.compliancestatus and !obj.comments to further narrow down the source of the error.